# Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object

Tags: node.js, json, web3js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://foodchain-node1.etherhost.org:22001');
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xA4fafbE0ea4823e262b4916EF93CC5A6306A5DBc";

async function eventQuery(){
    'use strict';
    var fs = require('fs');
    var data = fs.readFileSync('food3.abi', 'utf-8');
    //console.log(data);
    //console.log(typeof JSON.parse(data).interface)
    const CONTRACT_ABI = JSON.parse(data);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    const START_BLOCK = 7700000;
    const END_BLOCK = 7701000;
    contract.getPastEvents("FoodSection",
        {                               
            fromBlock: START_BLOCK,     
            toBlock: END_BLOCK     
        })                              
    .then(events => console.log(events))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

eventQuery();
```

I created this code and everytime I ran it, it returns the error of
"Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object."
I am guessing it have something to do with the json parse of the 'food3.abi' file but I do not know how to correct it.
Could somebody please let me know what is my mistake and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried running your example and i didn't get an error, so probably there is an issue with the `food3.abi` file you have(e.g if you copy pasted the ABI from somewhere you may have missed [ ]).

This is the steps i followed. Maybe it will work for you as well.

1. Install solc `npm install -g solc`
2. Compile contract `solcjs --abi contract.sol`. This will create a `contract_sol_contract.abi` file in the same folder
3. Use the generated abi file in the `fs.readFileSync()` statement

Comment: Maybe some more info about how you generated the food3.abi file will help

Answer (score 2):

You should check food3.abi, the json file usually has a property called abi which is what is actually needed here.

`const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI.abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);`

Comment: Adding `.abi` after `CONTRACT_ABI` did the trick, thanks!